# How to convert String values in a dictionary to a list in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to read contents from file which has the following content

```
XXX f,d,c,e
DDD f,d,c,g
ZZZ f,d,h,g
KKK c,c,d,d
```

I have to read this as a dictionary in the below format. The below should be my final output -

```
{'XXX': ['f','d','c','e'], 'DDD': ['f','d','c','g'], 'ZZZ': ['f','d','h','g'], 'KKK': ['c','c','d','d']}
```

But I managed to read it as dictionary in the below format. But the values are not in list format.
Current output

```
{'XXX': 'f,d,c,e', 'DDD': 'f,d,c,g', 'ZZZ': 'f,d,h,g', 'KKK': 'c,c,d,d'}
```

Can someone help to convert the values as list or directly read it as list from file?

Comment: See [str.split(',')](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: Do you have some code to show what you have already tried? Please add your code.

Comment: But the value of the desired output dict is not a list of strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.split(",")`

**Ex:**

```
d = {'XXX': 'f,d,c,e', 'DDD': 'f,d,c,g', 'ZZZ': 'f,d,h,g', 'KKK': 'c,c,d,d'}
d = {k: v.split(",") for k,v in d.items()}
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'XXX': ['f', 'd', 'c', 'e'], 'ZZZ': ['f', 'd', 'h', 'g'], 'KKK': ['c', 'c', 'd', 'd'], 'DDD': ['f', 'd', 'c', 'g']}
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh for your help. I got the output.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in one line:

```
a = '''XXX f,d,c,e
    DDD f,d,c,g
    ZZZ f,d,h,g
    KKK c,c,d,d'''

{k:v.split(',') for k,v in {l.split()[0]:l.split()[1] for l in a.split('\n')}.items()}
```

the out put:

```
{'XXX': ['f', 'd', 'c', 'e'],
 'DDD': ['f', 'd', 'c', 'g'],
 'ZZZ': ['f', 'd', 'h', 'g'],
 'KKK': ['c', 'c', 'd', 'd']}
```